# Git checkout just a subdirectory

Tags: git, clone, subdirectory, git-checkout

Please note: I am *not* looking for git sparse checkout, nor is this question a duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

In git, is it possible to clone or checkout just a subdirectory, into the current directory? In svn, you would do this by extending the URL. For example, instead of checking out `http://server/repo` you would checkout `http://server/repo/subdir`

The difference between sparse checkout and checking out only a subdir, is that a sparse checkout still creates a local directory `subdir`. I don't want a subdirectory called `subdir`. I want the contents of `subdir` to be checked out into the top level of my working copy.

An example use case would be:

- I clone https://github.com/jquerytools/www.git
- I don't like their `css` so I do a sparse checkout or use ignores to exclude their `css` from my checkout.
- I want to use the `source/css` subdirectory from https://github.com/mozfr/www.git and it must appear in the local `css` directory

Comment: see git subtree or git submodule.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help even a little bit. Did you understand the question?